# Magento - UPS shipping returns error "Missing or invalid ship from address line 1" - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, ups

I want to use UPS XML Shipping in one of my Magento Website.The website is from London, UK and we need to integrate UPS for UK.

We tried to integrate the same, and have cross-verified the credentials and all the other relevant information multiple times; yet, somehow the UPS XML Shipping is not working in it.

When I try to create a label for UPS (using button "ship" and checking "create shipping label") a popup appears (so far so good) BUT after I create my package and clicking "ok" I got below errors.

We are facing Error as below in UPS Shipping.

1) A shipment cannot have a KGS/IN or LBS/CM or OZS/CM as its unit of measurements

2) Missing or invalid ship from address line 1

3) Shipper Number 0847FE does not support pallet Contract Service

Post varilable with value as below.

```
packages[1][items][1611][...    10

packages[1][items][1611][...    HEAD LAMP

packages[1][items][1611][...    1611

packages[1][items][1611][...    10.0000

packages[1][items][1611][...    471

packages[1][items][1611][...    1

packages[1][items][1611][...    8.0000

packages[1][params][conta...    24

packages[1][params][conte...    

packages[1][params][conte...    

packages[1][params][custo...    10

packages[1][params][deliv...    0

packages[1][params][dimen...    CENTIMETER

packages[1][params][heigh...    

packages[1][params][lengt...    

packages[1][params][weigh...    8

packages[1][params][weigh...    KILOGRAM

packages[1][params][width...    

shipment[comment_text]  

shipment[create_shipping_...    1

shipment[items][1611]   1
```

I have changed as per descrive in [LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29376/ups-shipping-label-magento-1-9) in below files for address lines but still didn't get shipping label and tracking number as well.

```
/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php

/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
```

Does someone have an idea about what is going on? please help me to clear out from it.

Thanks

Comment: Array output is truncated. Do you have the original xml request you are posting to UPS for this? And please use the formatting tools to keep things readable.

Comment: Thanks for comment @Melvyn but my question is 

When I try to create a label for UPS (using button "ship" and checking "create shipping label") a popup appears  BUT after I create my package and clicking "ok" , 
I got below errors.

1) A shipment cannot have a KGS/IN or LBS/CM or OZS/CM as its unit of measurements
2) Missing or invalid ship from address line 1
3) Shipper Number 0847FE does not support pallet Contract Service

Here, i m talking about Magento admin panel [Sales->order->orderdetail]

Comment: Are you shipping **to Canada**?

Answer (score 4):

> 1) A shipment cannot have a KGS/IN or LBS/CM or OZS/CM as its unit of
>   measurements

If your shipper country is GB use KGS/CM unit of measurements as The unit of
measurement must be valid for the Shipper country. KGS/IN is not valid combination you can use LBS/IN or KGS/CM as a unit of measurements valid for your shipper country.

> 2) Missing or invalid ship from address line 1

Configure your address line 1 in

`System->Configuration->Shipping Settings->Origin->Street Address`

it can be a maximum of 35 chars (including spaces)

> 3) Shipper Number 0847FE does not support pallet Contract Service

Your shipper number is not qualify for send pallets contact UPS support team or change package Container to some thing other than pallets (Example: Customer Packaging ) in

```
System->Configuration->Shipping Methods->UPS->Container
```

Hope this will help and you should be able to create label using UPS

Comment: My store in India, so my default weight KGS. UPS for USA shipping, what i need to do with "Weight Unit"   KGS or LBS?

Comment: @zus it depends on shipper country of shipper account in UPS. if shipper is from India Weight Unit should be "KGS" and if shipper is from USA Weight Unit should be "LBS"

Comment: hi minesh, my website base country India, so my all products weight as KGS. I need to ship to an overseas country using UPS, and also i am configured UPS settings as "Weight Unit = KGS", after try to place an order the error is, "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."  How can i solve this weight unit issue?

Comment: @zus enable debug for ups and try again. you would see log of ups shipping method under `var/log` folder and paste your log here.