# How to setup UPS shipping for Canadian origins

Tags: shipping-methods, ups

How do we setup shipping for Canadian orgins?  I get this error:

```
2015-10-06T20:32:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => Array
        (
            [accept_UPS_license_agreement] => yes
            [10_action] => 4
            [13_product] => GNDRES
            [14_origCountry] => CA
            [15_origPostal] => L1W3T9
            [origCity] => Pickering
            [19_destPostal] => L1H 5A4
            [22_destCountry] => CA
            [23_weight] => 0.1
            [47_rate_chart] => Customer Counter
            [48_container] => 00
            [49_residential] => 01
            [weight_std] => lbs
        )

    [result] => UPSOnLine5%Origin postal code must have five digits.%0000

    [__pid] => 21830
)
```

Everything is setup for Canadian currencies, it works fine if I change to origin to a US address. [but that's not the origin]

Does this actually work or do we need another plugin?

Comment: What is your shipper country CA or US ?

Comment: Here is validation rules for ShipFrom Post code For UPS :
Required if ShipFrom tag is in the XML and the ShipFrom country is the US, Puerto Rico. For US, Puerto Rico must be valid 5 or 9 digit postal codes. ‘.’
The character - may be used to separate the first five digits and the last four digits. If the ShipFrom country is CA, then the postal code must be 6 alphanumeric characters
whose format is A#A#A# where A is an uppercase letter and # is a digit. For all other countries the postal code is optional and must be no more than 9 alphanumeric characters
long

Comment: and as per this rule your post code is correct please contact UPS support team at uoltects@ups.com

Comment: @Sean Kimball - Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @MineshPatel My store running in India, so all products weight in KGS, if i try to UPS for international customer i am getting an error like : This measurement system is not valid for the selected country, How can i solve this issue?

Comment: @zus added comment [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84849/31150)